# "Like" Button with ZF2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

Couple of weeks ago I started working with ZF2, with a new project. I need some guidance about how to implement a 
feature. I want to implement a "Like" button (E.g FB like button) this button will be attach to almost all the components
like uploaded Photos, Videos, Etc.., Honestly I don't have a much idea how this should be implemented with ZF2. Can someone 
put me to the correct track. I don't need to know how to code it but just need to know what path should I take what is the best way ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, since a Facebook Button is nothing but a little Javascript-Snippet with a `URL` attached, all you'd have to do is to build a `ViewHelper` that get's the current `Route` or `URL` injected. That `ViewHelper` would then print out the JS Snippet and create the specific like button.

The JavaScript that is required for that would be injected using the `head*()`-viewHelpers.

No need to make it any more complex than that. Furthermore i see no easier solution than this, as the position of the button and the displayStatus would be different on pretty much each page.